# Reading element from JSON object fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to read something from a JSON object with JavaScript and jQuery.
But I keep getting thrown an exception that "code" is not set. What I want to do, is read a country code from a string, and pre fill an input field depending on what the string is.

This is my code:

```
<input type="text" name="country">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var countryData = [{
        "id": 23,
        "code": "DK",
        "country": "Danmark",
        "phone_phoneext": "+45"
    }, {
        "id": 24,
        "code": "SE",
        "country": "Sverige",
        "phone_phoneext": "+46"
    }, {
        "id": 25,
        "code": "NO",
        "country": "Norge",
        "phone_phoneext": "+47"
    }];

    var countryCookie = "DK"; //Will be read from a cookie later 

    function getCountryByCookie(countryCode) {
        return countryData.filter(

        function (countryData) {
            return countryData.code == code
        });
    }

    try {
        var foundCountryCookie = getCountryByCookie(countryCookie);
        $("input[name=country]").val(foundCountryCookie[0].country);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Should this `function(countryData){return countryData.code == code}` be `function(countryData){return countryData.code == countryCode}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because you never declare or set the variable `code`.

```
function getCountryByCookie(countryCode) {
     return countryData.filter(
         function(countryData){return countryData.code == countryCode} //countryCode instead of just code
     );
}
```

Comment: Bah. What a howler :-) Thanks a lot